# Zero Cross TRIAC circuit for regulator fails on voltage spike

Tags: arduino, voltage, triac, snubber, zero-crossing

I am using a ZC TRIAC circuit to switch and regulate an electric appliance e.g. a table fan, a electric drill etc.

I must confirm that proper **SNUBBER** circuit is used and everything works fine. I have created a switch board with switch and regulate buttons with the triac underneath , controlled by an ARDUINO. I just have to plug it in a socket of a switch board on the wall and plug in the appliance in the socket in my triac switch board and everything works fine.

Now the problem starts when an appliance in my wall switch board ( e.g. tubelight ) **is turned off** ( no problem while turning on ). Whenever another appliance is turned off, the ZC circuit restarts the ARDUINO. If the ZC circuit is taken out, everything is ok.

So the problem is definitely with the ZC circuit, but I have no clue what the problem is. Any help will be greatly appreciated

[image: I have also tried changing the 4N25GV IC but that did not help either. It works for some time then again fails]

Comment: A schematic would give us a clue......

Comment: I have attached the schematic. I have also tried changing the 4N25GV IC but that did not help either. It works for some time then again fails

Comment: Is the Arduino processing the signal in software? If so, could you modify the s/w to ignore very short pulses? Also, you might want to investigate using an [X-capacitor](http://www.justradios.com/safetytips.html) across the AC side of the bridge rectifier. P.S. you forgot to draw the fuse in the circuit.